# DSR and AODV C++ implementation

Tags: c++, networking

I have to implement a simple DSR and AODV program with C++. 
However, the graph of nodes is given and I don't know how to implement these nodes so I could write the code? do I consider each node as array or pointer? any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoY8T.png)

Comment: What is DSR and AODV? Double Sausage Roast and Anti Odor Dispenser Vent? You should always provide full name of a term which might be not well known and/or ambiguous.

Comment: 1) Dynamic Source Routing (DSR)
2) Ad-hoc On-Demand Distance Vector (AODV)

Comment: :) You can make a list or map or vector of nodes. Then you can make another list of connections consisting of two pointers to two nodes and the value of the connection. The second way is to create a list of nodes and inside each node list of neighboring nodes and values.

Comment: The best way is to create an object (class) with methods to insert/delete nodes and insert/delete connections. After that you can implement the calculations traversing through this data.

Comment: Thank you for you time. I just have another question. how to create a list with two pointer to two nodes?

Comment: `class Node;
std::set<std::tuple<Node *, Node *, int>> connections;`
"int" would be the value of the connection.
Google for these.

Comment: Or maybe:
`std::map<std::pair<Node *, Node *>, int> connections;`
This is better for searching through connections.